# How to create a folding ribbon heading with inside gradient?

Tags: html, css, ribbon, heading

I'm looking for creating a heading with a wraparound effect, kind of like this tutorial here:

http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/quick-tip-practical-css-shapes--net-11749

Except I want it kind of in a more rounded shape than that, like in this school website:

http://www.mowbray-p.schools.nsw.edu.au/home

But I zoomed in and by the pixelation of the banner you can tell it's an image.

[image: Banner]

So I'm wondering, how do I create this (including gradient) with actual coding?

Any ideas/help appreciated! :)

Edit: code is not limited to HTML and CSS.

Comment: That's a very hard task to make it pure CSS. The most probably thing is that you will not obtain answers, too broad at least. The common way to make it is with images, since the shape is very complex to accomplish with CSS

Comment: Is there another way to create it other than CSS?

Comment: I tell you, with images, as the original example is maded.

Comment: `Edit: code is not limited to HTML and CSS.`Wrong, if you want to style some in a web, html and CSS is essential.

Comment: I meant to say you don't have to just use the two languages

Comment: You need to try something by yourself, otherwise this should be closed as offtopic. The solution is easy: make a image and position it with CSS.

Comment: Use `::before`s and `::after`s

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, my solution is not the best, has a big room for improvement, but it works. I have recreated this ribbon-menu from the site you mentioned using only CSS. Top and bottom ribbons are `absolute` positioned, each have gradient inserted using `:before` selector, the rest is to set the right `border-radius` for each element, nothing too fancy or too complicated.

https://jsfiddle.net/ny46og69/

Comment: Wow! You beat me at posting at 1 sec :D. Nice fiddle!

Comment: What do you mean by it has a big room for improvement? it looks fine!

Answer (score 0):

It's simple actually. You just want to use `::before`s and `::after`s

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background-color: #09f;
}

nav {
  width:200px;
  height:80px;
  position:relative;
  margin:50px;
}

nav > .nav-container {
  width:100%;
  height:80px;
  background-color:#CCEBFF;
  position:relative;
  z-index:2;
  border-radius: 15px 15px 0 0;
}

nav > .nav-container > div {
  position:absolute;
  top:32px;
  width:100%;
  height:36px;
  background-color: #fff;
  padding:10px;
}

nav::before,
nav::after{
  content: " ";
  position:absolute;
  border-radius:15px;
}

nav::before {
  top:0px;
  left:-22px;
  width:44px;
  height:68px;
  background-color:#fff;
}

nav::after {
  top:2px;
  left:-20px;
  width:40px;
  height:30px;
  background: #dddddd;
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #dddddd 0%, #999999 100%);
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  #dddddd 0%,#999999 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  #dddddd 0%,#999999 100%);
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(   startColorstr='#dddddd',   endColorstr='#999999',GradientType=0 );
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <div class="nav-container">
    <div>
      All your items
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Pretty neatly made! What about the left side?